# Javascript: Populating a table with images from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm trying to create a javascript table with rows of 10 from an array of images but with no luck.  The table works but each cell just has [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the image.

The code I tried is below.

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = new Image();
    myArray[i].src = i + '.gif'; 
}

document.writeln('<table border = 1 >');
for(var j=0; j<myArray.length; j++){
    if(j%10==0 && j!==0){
    document.writeln('</tr><tr>');
    }
    document.writeln('<td >' + myArray[j] + '</td>');
}
document.writeln('</tr></table>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at those two lines from your code:

```
myArray[i] = new Image();

document.writeln('<td >' + myArray[j] + '</td>'); // wrong - myArray has to be a string
```

So, myArray is an *image*, but in the second line you're trying to make it a string - `"<td>" + myArray[j] + "<td>"` - this is a way to concatenate strings, not objects. (in this case, myArray[i] is implicitly converted to a string - "htmlImageElement" or whatever)

What you need is to display an `<img>` tag with the `src` attribute set to the one in myArray[i], i.e.:

```
document.writeln('<td ><img src="' + myArray[j].src + '" /></td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is this:

```
$(document.createElement('table'));
var result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    result+= '<tr><td><img src="' + myArray[i] + '" alt=""/></td></tr>'
}
$('#table').append(result);
```

Or this:

```
$(document.createElement('table'));
var result = "";
myArray.map(function(item){
    result+= '<tr><td><img src="' + item + '" alt=""/></td></tr>'
})
$('#table').append(result);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I get the string vs object explanation (I think) so have amended that line.  What I get now is a table of broken image icons instead of my images so I must be close but have missed something along the way.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course I could always just include the .src as stated above and it works perfectly.  Now resolved, Many thanks.

Comment: Good to know! Can you mark my answer as accepted please? Also, I've tried my solution and I didn't get any broken images, did you still use myArray[i] = new Image()? As this is not necessary, assuming inside myArray are a bunch of image urls.